# Question about small variation in path in derivation of Euler-Lagrange equation?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-calculus

Consider the first derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation shown in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation#Statement). We begin by considering the path $f(x)$ that yields stationary action. We then consider a new path with the addition of a small perturbation given by:

$$g_\epsilon(x) \ = \ f(x) \ + \ \epsilon \eta(x)$$

Here is my concern: At no point in this proof do we actually make use of the fact that $\epsilon$ is small. It would seem as though this proof would hold for any size of $\epsilon$. I do understand that $\epsilon$ terms of order greater than or equal to $2$ in the Taylor expansion of the action (in terms of $\epsilon$) will become negligible if $\epsilon$ is very small. Along with the absence of a first-order $\epsilon$ term, this makes the action at the original and perturbed path essentially the same, but this doesn't seem to have anything to do with the proof itself.

Comment: Someone may correct me but $\epsilon$ in this case can take any value. $g_\epsilon(x)$ defines a set of curves.

Comment: Oh interesting, would saying that $\epsilon$ is small be incorrect then? (I've seen this on Wikipedia and a few other places)

Comment: Someone more qualified could give a better answer than me I'm afraid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106929/discussion-between-vivek-and-jack-ceroni).